# declare and use variable in a template Angular 4: is it possible to simplify this example?

Tags: angular, forms, variables, angular4-forms

I've significantly cut my code.
Here is the significant part. Angular4. Template.

**Original code:**

```
<div *ngIf="getData(places).length > 0">
  <select>
     <option *ngFor="let place of getData(places)" [ngValue]="place.placeId">{{place.description}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As you may see `getData` function used twice. The first time it's used just to decide whether to display the whole block at all as it could be empty. This is a must.

I've tried to simplify it with no errors. The shortest way with the same functionality I've got is the
**Improved code** below:

```
<div *ngIf="getData(places); let myList">
  <div *ngIf="myList.length > 0">
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let place of myList" [ngValue]="place.placeId">{{place.description}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The bad thing is the Improved code has an additional wrapper - an additional div.

Is it possible to avoid this additional div? I don't know if I can combine that two *ngIfs if the second ngIf uses the variable declared in the first one.

Comment: Use `ng-container` instead of `div`

Comment: Why not just `<select *ngIf="myList.length"`?

Comment: To begin with, don't use function in ngIf expression for performance reasons. They are called every single angular check.

Comment: Why not just <select *ngIf="myList.length"  - valid question. Thank ou. This is just because the code has significantly simplified. I was curious if it is possible do not break the structure. Looks like ng-container is the way to go. At least it work. However, still interesting if it is possible to do without an additional ng-container and without additional tags.  But, your answer answers the question. Thank you.